# BASH find which port a USB drive is attached to by the PCI ID

Tags: linux, bash, usb, label, pci

Basically I need to verify that a USB Drive is connected to a certain USB Port.   I have the following:

USB Drives are labeled virtually:

- White, Green, Red

I have 3 USB Ports that are also labeled physically:

- White, Green, Red

Using BLKID I can receive information from the drives such as

```
BLKID Example
/dec/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="WHTIE" UUID="78FE-870D" TYPE="vfat"
```

Therefore I know a lot about the drive itself by only knowing the label. Now I using LSPCI I can get the information about the USB port as I know the ID's of each bridge.  For example:

```
LSPCI Example
0a.00.0 USB Controller: some info 4d88
```

So that last part 4d88 is the PCI ID.

So I know the PCI ID's of each port and need to match them up to the USB Drive itself such as:

- 4d88 = WHITE
- 4dC0 = GREEN
- 4d84 = RED

I don't know how to match / check that relationship.  Any help will be appreciated.

**ANSWER:** Thanks for all the help.

```
#!/bin/bash

#variables
error="ERROR : Incorrect Command use 'usb_pci.sh'"
pci="USB PCI Check Successful"

errorstatus_white_pci="ERROR : USB PCI FAILED : WHITE Drive"
errorstatus_green_pci="ERROR : USB PCI FAILED : GREEN Drive"
errorstatus_red_pci="ERROR : USB PCI FAILED : RED Drive"

pci_check_white=4dc9
pci_check_green=4d81
pci_check_red=4dc5

#Takes USB label and gets /sys/block/sd?
echo "checking path for USB Label" 
path_white=$(blkid | grep WHITE | cut -d : -f 1 | sed 's|[0-9]*$||; s|^/dev/|/sys/block/|')
echo "white: "$path_white
path_green=$(blkid | grep GREEN | cut -d : -f 1 | sed 's|[0-9]*$||; s|^/dev/|/sys/block/|')
echo "green: "$path_green
path_red=$(blkid | grep RED | cut -d : -f 1 | sed 's|[0-9]*$||; s|^/dev/|/sys/block/|')
echo "red: "$path_red

#Takes /sys/block/sd? and gets PCI Path xx:xx.x
echo "checking path to PCI path" 
pci_path_white=$(ls -l ${path_white} | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13)
echo "white: "$pci_path_white
pci_path_green=$(ls -l ${path_green} | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13)
echo "green: "$pci_path_green
pci_path_red=$(ls -l ${path_red} | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13)
echo "red: "$pci_path_red

#Takes xx:xx.x and gets the PCI Device ID xxxx
echo "checking PCI path to PCI Device ID" 
pci_device_id_white=$(lspci -s ${pci_path_white} | tail -c -5)
echo "white: "$pci_device_id_white
pci_device_id_green=$(lspci -s ${pci_path_green} | tail -c -5)
echo "green: "$pci_device_id_green
pci_device_id_red=$(lspci -s ${pci_path_red} | tail -c -5)
echo "red: "$pci_device_id_red

#check if pci_device_id_xxxx = pci_check_xxxx
echo "checking PCI Device ID equals what it should" 
if [ $pci_device_id_white = $pci_check_white ] ; then
    echo "WHITE USB PCI Check Successful"
else
    echo $errorstatus_white_pci
    exit 1
fi
if [ $pci_device_id_green = $pci_check_green ] ; then
    echo "GREEN USB PCI Check Successful"
else
    echo $errorstatus_green_pci
    exit 1
fi
if [ $pci_device_id_red = $pci_check_red ] ; then
    echo "RED USB PCI Check Successful"
else
    echo $errorstatus_red_pci
    exit 1
fi
echo $pci
exit 0
```

Edit:

As requested dumps of lspci, lsusb, blkid.

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 0104 (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 0126 (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c3a (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c2d (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c20 (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c10 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c14 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c16 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c1a (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c26 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c4f (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 82801 SATA RAID Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Unknown device 1c22 (rev 04)
08:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. PES4T4 PCI Express Switch (rev 0e)
09:02.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. PES4T4 PCI Express Switch (rev 0e)
09:03.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. PES4T4 PCI Express Switch (rev 0e)
09:04.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Device Technology, Inc. PES4T4 PCI Express Switch (rev 0e)
0a:00.0 USB Controller:  Unknown device 4d88
0a:00.1 USB Controller:  Unknown device 4dc9
0a:00.2 System peripheral:  Unknown device 4dca
0a:00.3 Communication controller:  Unknown device 4d8b
0b:00.0 USB Controller:  Unknown device 4dc0
0b:00.1 USB Controller:  Unknown device 4d81
0b:00.2 System peripheral:  Unknown device 4d8e
0b:00.3 Serial controller:  Unknown device 4dcf
0c:00.0 USB Controller:  Unknown device 4d84
0c:00.1 USB Controller:  Unknown device 4dc5
0c:00.2 System peripheral:  Unknown device 4dc6
0c:00.3 Communication controller:  Unknown device 4d87
0d:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Unknown device 8221 (rev 05)
0d:00.1 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Unknown device 8231 (rev 03)

lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0718:063d Imation Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse

blkid
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01: TYPE="swap" UUID="6b361baf-08ae-4f2c-933b-5028c15b6fb5" 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00: UUID="d15840ac-0073-483d-b630-7d2a497eaac9" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="/boot" UUID="39331b93-a08d-45b5-b1ea-fcc6586be7bd" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00: UUID="d15840ac-0073-483d-b630-7d2a497eaac9" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01: TYPE="swap" UUID="6b361baf-08ae-4f2c-933b-5028c15b6fb5" 
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="WHITE" UUID="78FE-870D" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdc1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="GREEN" UUID="61FE-B32E" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdd1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="RED" UUID="E5DB-4A1A" TYPE="vfat"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it on my system:

**Step 1:** Find the device node:

```
# blkid | grep MyDisk
/dev/sdj1: LABEL="MyDisk-0" UUID="4876-5945" TYPE="vfat"
```

The device node is `/dev/sdj1`.

**Step 2:** `/sys` is your friend:

```
# ll /sys/block/sdj
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb  3 00:40 /sys/block/sdj -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host15/target15:0:0/15:0:0:0/block/sdj/
```

The symbolic link target above contains a *lot* of useful information, including the path from your flash drive back to the PCI bridge via the SCSI and USB subsystems.

**Step 3:** From the link target above isolate the PCI bus ID (`00:1a.7` in this case) and check with `lspci`:

```
# lspci | grep 00:1a.7
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
```

If in doubt, inspect the `lspci` output visually...

**EDIT:**

Here is an extremely crude and extremely fragile way to automate the process above:

```
blkid |
    grep Label |
    cut -d : -f 1 |
    sed 's|[0-9]*$||; s|^/dev/|/sys/block/|' |
    xargs readlink |
    cut -d / -f 4 |
    xargs -n 1 lspci -s
```

NOTE: This works on my system, but it is by no means safe (or recommended):

1. It will break if a kernel update changes the layout of the `/sys` filesystem.
2. It can break if you have a different device layout, although you should be able to adjust for that.

Comment: I need to fully automate the process. Are you saying that the above 3 steps can be automated and put together without visual inspection?

Comment: @bing281: well, they can be automated, but the `/sys` layout occasionally changes in newer kernels. Why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: I need to verify that certain paths are programmed correctly in the bridge and do not have any faults.  Therefore I need to stick in 3 usb sticks and verify with code they are in the slots I think they are in given that I know what PCI-ID I am assigning to each USB Port via programming the EEPROM chip internally

Comment: Can you edit your question with the full output of `lspci` and `lsusb`? I have seen embedded targets where all USB ports are on the same controller via a single hub...

Comment: Strangely I get permissio denied even though I am running as root using the edit code above.

Comment: @bing281: permission denied to do what?

Comment: i think it is in the /sys/block part

Comment: @bing281: 1. w.r.t. to your earlier comment - I only see one `00:1c.3` device in `lspci`. 2. Would you mind pasting the exact error message from my snippet?

Comment: I agree I made a mistake with that earlier comment it would seem.

Comment: I used a lot of your code to answer the question thank you very much.  See above in my question for the answer.